# show method automatically running upon custom type construction

Tags: julia

Every time I call a constructor for a custom-type, the `show` method for that type runs. I cannot work out why. Reproducible example follows:

I have a module:

```
module ctbTestModule1

import  Base.show

export  MyType1

type MyType1
    function MyType1()
        new()
    end
end

function show(io::IO, a::MyType1)
    println("hello world")
end

end
```

I open up a fresh julia session in the REPL and type:

```
using ctbTestModule1
z = MyType1()
```

The following prints to the console when I run the line `z = MyType1()`:

```
hello world
```

How is the `show` method being called here? It certainly doesn't appear to be called in the inner constructor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The REPL (Read-evaluate-print loop) evaluates and prints every statement.

What you describe is the usual behavior.

Run `z = 1` in your REPL and the printed output will be `1`.

Likewise, your `z` is a `MyType1` which is displayed as `hello world`.

If you want to suppress the output in the REPL finish your statement with a semicolon `;`:

```
z = MyType1();
```

So, to answer your question: Yes, if you create an instance of a type in the REPL, the result is shown by calling the *show()* function of that type.

Comment: Yep, you're totally right. Not sure what was going through my brain here. I somehow got confused between statements made at the REPL and statements made inside a function. Thanks for letting me down gently :-)